# Special cases of SAT and corresponding #SAT with complexity a most O(n^2) AND that have efficient algorithms for generating instances?

Tags: logic, enumeration, time-complexity, counting, satisfiability

I am interested in learning about special cases of boolean satisfiability problems that are known to be polynomial (or more realistically, O(N^2)). These cases should also have efficient algorithm for actually generating all satisfactory instances, where by efficient I mean it takes O(N #SAT) to generate a sequence of all the instances. It is possible that the second condition implies the first, but it is not clear to me.

Trivial example: 1SAT :)

Trivial example: 2SAT with "chains" of clauses, so that the graph joining variables with clauses is a line.

Is there a list of more somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this question would do better at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Wow, thanks. Didn't know of this stackexchange site. I was thinking to post on mathoverflow for a moment, but it felt more CS-like, so probably that is the perfect place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [The Complexity of Satisfiability Problems](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/lieber/courses/csg260/f06/materials/papers/max-sat/p216-schaefer.pdf) by Schaefer:

> We show that (assuming P != NP) SAT(S) is polynomial-time decidable only if at least one of the following conditions holds:
>
> (a) Every relation in S is satisfied when all variables are 0.
>
> (b) Every relation in S is satisfied when all variables are 1.
>
> (c) Every relation in S is definable by a CNF formula in which each conjunct has at most one negated variable.
>
> (d) Every relation in S is definable by a CNF formula in which each conjunct has at most one unnegated variable.
>
> (e) Every relation in S is definable by a CNF formula having at most 2 literals in each conjunct.
>
> (f) Every relation in S is the set of solutions of a system of linear equation over the two-element field {0,1}.

The first two are solvable O(1), the next three O(n) and the last O(n^3) (I think).  So the SAT instances you want are in one of the first five classes.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I'm still chewing on the question of efficient enumeration of solutions, but (c)-(e) at least solves the existence problem in a straightforward way.